# How to transform class-based React-Redux code using Hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, thunk

I am learning React/Redux and I am trying to refactor this code from class-based to functional/hooks-based code. The application is an exercise I am working on, it has three components Posts.js where I fetch a list of posts from typicode.com. Each post from the fetched list has a button attacked.
On onClick, it should show details for each post (PostDetails.js and Comments.js):

[image: Concept]

At the moment, both Posts and Comments are class-based components. I need to:

Step 1: Change them to be functional components and use React Hooks but still keep connect(), mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps;

Step 2: Implement React-Redux hooks (UseSelector, useDispatch)

App.js

```
//imports...
const App = () => {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <div><Posts /></div>
            <div><PostDetails /></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

actions

```
import jsonPlaceholder from '../apis/jsonPlaceholder';

export const fetchPosts = () => async dispatch => {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get('/posts');
    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_POSTS', payload: response.data})
};


export const selectPost = post => {
    return ({
        type: 'POST_SELECTED',
        payload: post
    })
}


export const fetchComments = (id) => async dispatch => {
    const response = await jsonPlaceholder.get(`/comments?postId=${id}`);
    dispatch({type: 'FETCH_COMMENTS', payload: response.data})
}
```

reducers

```
export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_POSTS':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default (selectedPost = null, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'POST_SELECTED') {
        return action.payload;
    }
    return selectedPost;
}

export default (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_COMMENTS':
            return action.payload;
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

export default combineReducers({
    posts: postsReducer,
    selectedPost: selectedPostReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer
})
```

components/Posts.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchPosts, selectPost } from '../actions';
import '../styles/posts.scss';


class Posts extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchPosts()
    }

    renderPosts() {
        return this.props.posts.map(post => {
            if (post.id <= 10)              
            return (
                <div className='item' key={post.id}>
                    <div className="title">
                        <h4>{post.title}</h4>
                    </div>
                    <button
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.props.selectPost(post)
                            console.log(post)
                        }
                    }>Open</button>
                    <hr/>
                </div>
                )
         })
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="list">
                { this.renderPosts() }
            </div>
        )
  }
    
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        posts: state.posts,
        selectedPost: state.post
    }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = {
    fetchPosts,
    selectPost
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Posts);
```

components/PostDetails.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Comments from './Comments'

const PostDetails = ({ post }) => {
    if (!post) {
        return <div>Select a post</div>
    }
    return (
        <div className="post-details">
            <div className="post-content">
                <h3>{post.title}</h3>
                <p>{post.body}</p>
                <hr/>
            </div>
            <div className="comments-detail">
                <Comments postId={post.id}/>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {post: state.selectedPost}
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(PostDetails);
```

components/Comments.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchComments } from '../actions'

class Comments extends React.Component {
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if (this.props.postId && this.props.postId !== prevProps.postId){
            this.props.fetchComments(this.props.postId)
        }
    }

    renderComments() {
        console.log(this.props.comments)
        return this.props.comments.map(comment => {
            return (
                <div className="comment" key={comment.id}>
                    <div className="content">
                        <h5>{comment.name}</h5>
                        <p>{comment.body}</p>
                    </div>
                    <hr />
                </div>
            )
        })

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="comments">
                {this.renderComments()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {comments: state.comments}
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchComments})(Comments);
```

Comment: If you are converting this into functional components and hooks, you can use `useSelector` and `useDispatch` hooks and get rid of `connect`. Also, you can manage your component state using `useState` hook.

Comment: I know, but I am not sure how to implement them. I have a conflict between using Redux and useState to manage the state. @AjeetShah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a way to create `Posts` component:

I am assuming that when you **dispatch** `fetchPosts()` action, you are saving its response using reducers in Redux.

And, you don't need `fetchedPosts` in local component state as you already have this data in your Redux state.

```
const Posts = () => {
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  // const [fetchedPosts, setFetchedPosts] = useState([]) // NOT needed

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchPosts())
    // setFetchedPosts(posts) // NOT needed
    // console.log(posts) // NOT needed, its value may confuse you
  }, [])

  // Do this, if you want to see `posts` in browser log
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(posts)
  }, [posts])

  /* NOT needed
  const renderPosts = () => {
    posts.map((post) => {
      console.log(post)
    })
  } */

  return (
    <>
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div key={post.id}>{post.title}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Posts
```

Comment: Uhhh, great, this solved the infinite loop problem I had with useEffect. I also assumed that setState would not be needed, however, I was not exactly sure, so thanks for clearing that up! I am moving on to solving the next component! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I don't understand Ajeet. I am new to StackOverflow. Do I have to do something to give you a vote for helping me? It will be a pleasure mate :) Just let me know how